# Найти одинаковые точки в разных маршрутах

Tags: c++

Добрый вечер ,

подскажите пожалуйста , как можно и лучше проверить , есть ли элемент в другом маршруте , чтобы после посчитать сумму людей.. Например:
У меня есть маршрут 69-87-163-24 и маршрут 83-163-23-0 ..Во втором маршруте присутствует элемент 163 , значит я могу также создать маршрут 69-87-163-83 , 69-87-163-23 и 69-87-163-0.

```
for (auto i = route.begin(); i != route.end(); i++)
    {
        for (auto j = route.begin()+1; j != route.end(); j++)
     {
         if(.....)
         while(current!=end)
          {
            тут я пишу свой алгоритм , это я уже сделаю
          }
     }
    }
```

Главное, что мне нужно сделать , это проверит есть ли в других маршрутах эта точка,что я не могу сделать и думаю, что кроме двух циклов, нужно еще что-то добавить. Я вообще подумывал, а если сделать не как векторы , а как map , но думаю это ничего не изменит.

Спасибо заранее

Comment: Сортируете числа в маршруте и все становится сильно проще...

Comment: У меня все отсортировано , это такая задача, мне нужно просчитать , сколько  у меня линий , где человек может пересесть на другую ветку и поехать дальше .. И как мне сортировка поможет, если вам нетрудно , объясните подробнее.. У меня изначально все отсортировано , но одинаковые точки могут и должны быть , поэтому честно , как-то не дошло , что вы имели ввиду

Comment: Вообще я вижу вариант с битовыми полями, и тогда задача решается за 2*len(path) обращений к памяти. И тут даже сортировка не нужна.
И да, ваши примеры неотсортированы, если что ;-)

Comment: Тут вообще надо граф построить. И использовать потом какой-нибудь графовый алгоритм.

Answer (score 1):

Что такое ваш `route`? Просто вектор чисел?

Если уж вы хотите искать общую точку в *разных* маршрутах, то циклы должны идти по разным маршрутам:

```
for (auto i = route1.begin(); i != route1.end(); i++)
    for (auto j = route2.begin(); j != route2.end(); j++)
```

А если ваши `route` просто `vector<int>`, то `if` тоже прост:

```
if (*i == *j)
```

Ну, а когда заработает - тут уже можно будет подумать и об оптимизации :)